# Binding Listbox.ItemContainerStyle to current item property

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In my C# Windows Store App, I am trying to bind the `Visibility` property of `ListBoxItem` to a property that exists each of the `Items` in the `ItemsSource`.

Basically what I have is this:

```
class ExampleClass
{
     bool isVisible;
}
```

And in my datacontext I have a list of `ExampleClass`. What I am trying to do with the `ListBox` is the following:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ExampleLB" DataContext=""{StaticResource myContext}" ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleClassList}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <!--This doesnt work-->
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding isVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    /*More code here*/
</ListBox>
```

But I am unable to bind to the `isVisible` property inside of `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`. Instead it wants me to bind to another property of my `DataContext` instead. If I move down a few lines into the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` I am able to bind to the properties of the individual `ExampleClass` items in the `ItemsSource`, but why am I not able to bind to those same properties a few lines above inside of `ItemContainerStyle`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to a field. You'll need to make it a property and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
bool isVisible;
public bool IsVisible
{
  get { return isVisible;}
  set
  {
    isVisible = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already doing that. Sorry that wasn't clear in my post. Am I supposed to be able to bind to that IsVisible property so long as it is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? I ask because it already does (shouldn't have omitted that). My main issue is that when I try to set the binding of the Visibilty property there it wants me to bind to the a property of the DataContext instead of the List that the ListBox's ItemSource is bound to.